# Splitting and replacing character in a HEX value

Tags: python-2.7, split, hex

I have the following the value 2.
The value was converted using:

```
hex(2)
```

the value I get is: 0x2.

How is it possible to convert "0x2" to "00 02"?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: You want a code to just deal with this problem or you need a generic solution.

Comment: A generic solution. I encounter these values all the time and accept them as user input.